# "minefield" metaphorically

Tags: vocabulaire

In English we can use "minefield" for a situation fraught with difficulties, not necessarily an actual, physical minefield. Is there an equivalent in French, would they use "champs de mines" or "terrain miné" like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Terrain miné*** would be used as a metaphor in French.

Here's from a webpage from the website *[j'aime les mots](https://jaimelesmots.com/un-terrain-mine-etre-en-terrain-mine-ou-avancer-en-terrain-mine/)*:

> La locution nominale masculine "Un terrain miné" appartient au langage courant désigne :
> au sens propre : un terrain ou une zone garni de mines, d'explosifs, par extension : un lieu ou une zone dangereuse,
>
> et au sens figuré : un sujet délicat.
> On dit par exemple : "Avec l'adoption pour les couples homosexuels, le gouvernement avance en terrain miné".
> Ou : "Fais attention avec ce sujet : tu es en terrain miné".
> Et l'on peut également utiliser - dans le même registre de langue - l'expression "Terrain glissant" (Source : [www.larousse.fr](http://www.larousse.fr))

A few examples in context:

- *La prostitution de rue : un terrain miné ?* is the title of a [research paper](https://www.cairn.info/revue-journal-des-anthropologues-2008-1-page-387.htm).
- *Le terrain miné du racisme* is the title of an article in a literary magazine ([Esprit](https://esprit.presse.fr/article/lerner-gad/le-terrain-mine-du-racisme-12720)).
- *Lorsqu'un dogme, soit-il religieux ou économique, censure verbalement et/ou économiquement la science et les scientifiques, nous nous avançons en terrain miné: celui du déni de la vérité*. ([Le Journal de Montréal](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2014/10/22/de-galilee-a-stephen-harper))
- *Colline de Provence, un terrain miné !* In which the phrase is used with a double entendre in the [announcement of a debate](https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/provence-alpes-cote-d-azur/emissions/dimanche-politique-provence-alpes/colline-provence-terrain-mine-1579451.html) on hunting between hunters and hikers.

*[Champ de mines](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/champ_de_mines)* is not usually used in a metaphorical sense.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Collins dictionary the translation is "terrain miné".

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/minefield))
>
> 1. (literal) **champ  de mines**
> 2. (figurative) (= danger area)
>    a political **minefield** —  **un terrain miné**, politiquement

*Some examples from Collins dictionary, with user LPH's translations added*

- It would be a legal minefield. Times, Sunday Times (2012)
  Ce serait un terrain miné, du point de vue légal.
- At worst, they are a social minefield for all involved. Times, Sunday Times (2012)
  dans les pire conditions,  du point de vue social il constituent pour les intéressés un terrain miné.
- Tahrir Square is now a political minefield. Times, Sunday Times (2011)
  Maintenant, la place Tahir est politiquement un terrain miné.
- It's a legal and musical minefield. Times, Sunday Times (2011)
  C'est légalement et musicalement un terrain miné.

Comment: Why give all those examples in English rather than accept the perfectly good examples from in the first answer, all in French?

Comment: @Lambie When in English this phrase is modified by an adjective,  notice that in French there is no corresponding modification by an adjective in some cases; this, the Collins dictionary makes clear. I thought I could enlarge on that point, but I am sure what I did is far from exhausting all the possibilities. (for "a horrible minefield" you may say 'un affreux terrain miné", but for "political minefield" the phrase "terrain miné politique" is not a usual construction". I leave you to ponder the reason for that.

Comment: @Lambie My examples have nothing to do with the answer you quote. I wrote my answer independently, having read no part of the previous answer (what can you do in four minutes?); therefore, my examples are not meant in "refusal" of anything (reading my answer makes that immediately obvious).

Comment: 1- There's absolutely nothing to ponder about the straightforward grammatical usage that in French (same in English) adjectives modify nouns (*affreux* & *miné* both modify *terrain*), they cannot modify other adjectives: adverbs modify adjectives (*politiquement* modifies *miné*). 2- *Dans les pires conditions* doesn't mean "at worst". Other non idiomatic structures in your French sentences (but they're perfectly understandable), "real" French examples would have been  more supportive of your answer. 3- Just for maths's sake and nothing more implied: 16:38:42 - 16:10:20 = 00:18:22 (not 4).

Comment: @None Your answer is given to me as appearing at 16:19:20Z, mine at 16:24:23Z.  That is 5 minutes. Those are the times on my machine. How come your times are different?

Comment: @None Right, I forgot about that.

Comment: But there was a typing error in my answer and I can't have my maths wrong !  [16:38:42](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/49088/revisions) - 16:19:20 = 00:19:22 (not 4)

Answer (score 0):

Both are corrects in order to talk about a sensitive subject :

- Je n'aborderai pas ce sujet si j'étais toi, c'est un vrai champ de mines
- Tu veux parler de ses ex ? Tu t'aventures sur un terrain miné

also a similar expression :

- C'est une pente glissante / a slippery slope

Comment: Can you please support your answer with existing examples that *champ de mines* is indeed used metaphorically in French.